# pyparsing produces different results for asDict() and asList()

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have no ideas why pyparsing produces different results for asDict() and asList(). Please push me in the right direction.

```
import pyparsing as pp


WALRUS = pp.Keyword(':=').suppress()
number = pp.pyparsing_common.number
hex_number = pp.Literal('16#').suppress() + pp.Word(pp.hexnums+'_')
YesNo = pp.CaselessKeyword('YES').setParseAction(lambda t: True)\
        | pp.CaselessKeyword('NO').setParseAction(lambda t: False)
       
dblQuoString = pp.dblQuotedString().addParseAction(pp.removeQuotes)

propertyName = pp.Word(pp.alphas)('key') # + pp.Keyword(':=').suppress()
# value = dblQuoString | YesNo | hex_number | number | pp.Word(pp.alphanums + '.')  # the same result
value = pp.MatchFirst([dblQuoString,
                      YesNo,
                      hex_number,
                      number,
                      pp.Word(pp.alphanums + '.')]
                      )
value.setDebug()

key_value = propertyName + WALRUS + value('value')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_string = r"""Description := "Anything" """
    r = key_value.parseString(test_string)
    print(r.asDict())
    print(r.asList())
```

...and

```
{'key': 'Description', 'value': ['Anything']}
['Description', 'Anything']
```

Why 'Anything' is wrapped to list when result asDict?

I'm expected
{'key': 'Description', 'value': 'Anything'}

Comment: The question in the title (_Why does pyparsing wrap the result in a list?_ ) and the question/statement at the top of the post (_I have no ideas why piparsing produces different results for asDict() and asList()_) are not the same

Comment: Because pp can match multiple items. This structure stays the same no matter how many matches are in the result object.

Comment: @MatBailie But I've got the 'key': 'Description', not 'key': ['Description']. This is confused.

Comment: @oriraisfeld   value('value') - this is a shortcut for value.set_results_name('value')

Comment: @oriraisfeld Why directed at me?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is some kind of magic of pyparsing, the reasons for which are not entirely clear to me.

`value = dblQuoString` gives the output `'value': 'Anything'`

`value = dblQuoString ^ YesNo ^ hex_number ^ number ^ pp.Word(pp.alphanums + '.')` outputs a list  `'value': ['Anything']`

I decided for myself this way:

```
value.addParseAction(lambda t: t[0])
```